# Net DateTime.AddMonths(1) doesn't work the same as Javascript d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1)

Tags: .net, javascript, datetime

I have client side date validation that requires one particular Date to be one month from a different date so I use `d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1)` and mostly works just fine.

For end of month issues as in 1/31/2009, it returns 3/3/2009 and that's great - that's how I'd prefer it handle it.

In the code behind, I'm also generating this date but `DateTime.AddMonths(1)` returns 2/28/2009 so that's no good.

Is there some way around this?

Comment: I can't believe you think 3/3 is exactly one month after 1/31, but whatever!

Comment: it is exactly 30 days after 1/31...

Comment: It doesn't really matter what I think - That's the desired behavior of the powers that be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example of 1/31/2009 being changed to 3/3/2009 it sounds like you just want a way to advance the specified date by the number of days in its respective month. (Adding 31 days to the date if it's in January, 28 if in February during a non-leap year, etc...)

So your code would look something like:

```
d = d.AddDays(DateTime.DaysInMonth(d.Year, d.Month))
```

Answer (score 3):

The .NET function is undoubtedly more intelligent.  But if you want to dumb it down to behave like Javascript, add 31 days instead...

```
DateTime.AddDays(31)
```

Comment: You'd think so,  but for 2/1/2009 I want to get 3/1/2009 so that doesn't work.

Comment: Oh wow.  So one month after 1/31 is 3/3.  And one month after 2/1 is 3/1.  That makes a whole lot of sense, now doesn't it?

Comment: Oh i know it doesn't actually make sense but I have to make the website mimic the behavior of the desktop app that I have no control or say over.  Don't take it personal.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Josh's answer...  Not really sure why you want to do this but if you do want a specific behavior that is not built in, remember that you have the ability to write extensions.  This extension adds a method called "AddMonthsJ" to DateTime.  This gives the behavior that I think you are looking for and allows for it to be easily used.  You could modify the extension to be whatever you are looking for in changing months.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime myDate = DateTime.Parse("01/31/2009");

        myDate = myDate.AddMonthsJ(1);

        Console.WriteLine(myDate.ToShortDateString());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static DateTime AddMonthsJ(this DateTime oldDate, int months)
    {
        return (oldDate.AddDays(months * 31));
    }
}
```